# How can I use GeneralizedNewTypeDeriving to derive Vector and MVector?

Tags: haskell

Near the top of the [haddocks for Data.Vector.Unboxed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html), there is a discussion of how to use [GeneralizedNewTypeDeriving](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/newtype_deriving.html) to derive instances of `Vector` and `MVector`. The following example, edited to use `LANGUAGE` pragmas, is stated:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as M
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

newtype Foo = Foo Int

newtype instance U.MVector s Foo = MV_Int (U.MVector s Int)
newtype instance U.Vector Foo = V_Int (U.Vector Int)
deriving instance M.MVector U.MVector Foo
deriving instance G.Vector U.Vector Foo
instance U.Unbox Foo
```

However, it does not type check, failing with a long message that begins

```
• Couldn't match representation of type: m Int
                           with that of: m Foo
    arising from a use of ‘GHC.Prim.coerce’
  NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘m’ have;
    we must assume that the role is nominal
• In the expression:
    GHC.Prim.coerce
      @(U.MVector (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Int
        -> Int -> m Int)
      @(U.MVector (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Foo
        -> Int -> m Foo)
      (M.basicUnsafeRead @U.MVector @Int)
  In an equation for ‘M.basicUnsafeRead’:
      M.basicUnsafeRead
        = GHC.Prim.coerce
            @(U.MVector (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Int
              -> Int -> m Int)
            @(U.MVector (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) Foo
              -> Int -> m Foo)
            (M.basicUnsafeRead @U.MVector @Int)
```

The example is somehow wrong or lacking, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

I'll note that I can get this working quite easily with [Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2023-01-15/vector-th-unbox-0.2.2/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Deriving.html) (or by writing everything out manually):

```hs
derivingUnbox
  "Foo"
  [t|Foo -> Int|]
  [|\(Foo i) -> i|]
  [|Foo|]
```

My understanding of `GeneralizedNewTypeDeriving` is that it avoids the trivial application and removal of the constructor that I have to do in the above, so I'd like to be able to use it here if possible.

EDIT: Per request, I am using stack resolver [lts-19.33](https://www.stackage.org/lts-19.33), which is at `ghc-9.0.2`.

Comment: Might be helpful to specify the compiler version you're using. The vector docs probably refer to an older version that didn't take type roles seriously yet.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've updated the answer. If you would, please clarify what you mean by "tak[ing] type roles seriously."

Comment: Well, type roles were introduced to distinguish when `coerce` is actually safe. Initially, GHC would allow some incorrect coercions (when a type variable changes that does affect the internal implementation), which was subsequently made impossible by tracking which type variables affect the implementation and which don't. That, however, meant that some code which didn't propagate this information stopped working: even if the coercions were correct, the compiler wasn't able to prove it and thus rejected the code. That was my guess for what's causing your problem, but I was wrong (see answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently, *vector* version 0.13.0.0 got a change that allows deriving using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` with its classes ([changelog](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.0.0/changelog)). Indeed, before that, this just wasn't possible. Since you are using *vector* version 0.12.3.1 (via lts-19.33), the solution is to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I'll note for other stack users that there don't appear to be any snapshots as of this writing with vector higher than 0.12.3.1, including [nightly-2023-01-15](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/blob/master/nightly/2023/1/15.yaml), so the only way to do this (that I'm aware of) with stack is to specify `vector-0.13.0.0` under `extra-deps` and possibly `allow-newer: true` and then cross your fingers and hope nothing breaks.